# Everything turning black when pitching down

Tags: opengl

Just a quick questions about something that's occurring in my world. Every time I pitch my camera downward, everything starts turning black, and if I pitch upward, everything sort of intensifies.

I'm multiplying my normals by the normal matrix in the shader, and I'm multiplying my lights direction by the model view matrix.

If I leave the normal and light dir in world space everything ends up fine.

I thought putting them both in view space would not cause those weird things to happen?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: You are messing up something with your vectors/matrices, perhaps you forgot to put one vector in the correct space.